# spring RESTcontroller to accept dataURI

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I am running into a issue of using angularjs ng-img-crop and Spring-boot REST web service.I want to upload an image file from ng crop to my backend web service.

I tried writing a spring controller but it failed and  I couldnt find a good tutorial for this. help me resolve this basic request.

Thanks !!!

**app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', [
                         'ngRoute',
                         'myApp.view1',
                         'myApp.view2',
                         'myApp.version',
                         'ngImgCrop'
                         ])
                         .controller('Ctrl',['$scope','notify', function($scope,notify) {
                             $scope.myImage='';
                             $scope.myCroppedImage='';

                             var handleFileSelect=function(evt) {
                                 var file=evt.currentTarget.files[0];
                                 var reader = new FileReader();
                                 reader.onload = function (evt) {
                                     $scope.$apply(function($scope){
                                         $scope.myImage=evt.target.result;
                                     });
                                 };
                                 reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                             };
                             angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).on('change',handleFileSelect);
                             $scope.submit=function() {
                                 notify($scope.myCroppedImage);
                             };
                         }]).
                         factory('notify',['$http', function($http) { 
                               return function(myCroppedImage) {
                                   var name = 'vishnu';
                                   $http.post('http://localhost:8080/imageUpload', myCroppedImage)
                                   .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                     alert("success");
                                   })
                                   .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                       alert("fail");
                                   });
                               }
                         }])
```

**controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/imageUpload",method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String imageUpload(@RequestBody MultipartFile data){

    return "success";
}
```

when I run with the following request, I got some exception in the web service.

**Remote Address**:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/imageUpload
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1850
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:file://
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36**

**Request payload**
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAYAAACtWK6eAAAFIklEQVR4Xu3VsRHAMAzEsHj/pTOBXbB9pFchyLycz0eAwFXgsCF.......

**Response header**
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 24 Apr 2015 12:40:35 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked

**Exception in java** 
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request

Answer (score 0):

First of all your controller should looks like:

```
public ResponseEntity<Response> fileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
```

Use `@RequestParam` instead of `@RequestBody`, and send the file in a parameter with the same name you're using in the annotation.

Moreover, your request should be sent with type `multipart/form-data`. For example, a common html for would be:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="your url">
```

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. I do have angular at the front end and I am using ng-img-crop, kindly suggest me how to call using angular inside the javascript.